# Django : Enabling the cached template loader

Tags: django, templates, caching

I'v profiled my app in several situations and i came up with the conclusion that my bottle neck is the template rendering, Example dump

```
61323 function calls (59462 primitive calls) in 0.827 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.827    0.827 /home/haki/src/CalcSite/calc/views.py:279(home)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.815    0.815 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py:31(render)
      3/1    0.000    0.000    0.814    0.814 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py:151(render_to_string)
      4/1    0.000    0.000    0.808    0.808 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py:136(render)
      5/1    0.000    0.000    0.808    0.808 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py:133(_render)
    286/1    0.002    0.000    0.808    0.808 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py:836(render)
    714/2    0.000    0.000    0.808    0.404 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py:76(render_node)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.808    0.808 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py:100(render)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.803    0.134 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py:48(render)
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/performance/#the-cached-template-loader) enabling cached templates can have a significant effect on performance. So i tried adding this settings

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)
```

All my templates are in `app/templates`. I'm not using too mach template fragments  \ includes and all my app tags (~4) are thread safe. Looking at the db trace on this session i got 6 queries returning in 9ms - This is not the hold up.

I don't see any difference in the performance reports. Am i missing something here ? Am I testing it wrong ?

Comment: You're sorting by ctime so if your template tags are doing anything significant (like database access) it will be included. That last line of your list (the blocktag.render) renders other template sections in a tree like fashion so will include all the other. Give a full profile list and we might be able to see where the issue is

Answer (score 7):

The cached template loader still needs to render the templates. The savings come from not having the read the template again from the filesystem each time, saving IO.

If you want to cache the template, look at the {% cache %} template tags. But be aware you need to include the correct keys.

Comment: FYI from the Django docs: "Changed in Django 1.11: The automatic enabling of the cached template loader when debug is False was added."

Answer (score 4):

From Django 1.8+ you now place it in the [`OPTIONS` block of the `TEMPLATES` setting.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)

Comment: FYI, the syntax for this is quite different to what the OP was trying to use.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader